# OIOUBL namespace for BuyersItemIdentification in invoice

Tags: xml, xsd, edi

Our invoice numbers does not always match our suppliers, so I have added **BuyersItemIdentification**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Invoice xsi:schemaLocation="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:Invoice-2 UBL-Invoice-2.0.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:Invoice-2" xmlns:cac="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonAggregateComponents-2" xmlns:cbc="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonBasicComponents-2" xmlns:ccts="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CoreComponentParameters-2" xmlns:sdt="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:SpecializedDatatypes-2" xmlns:udt="urn:un:unece:uncefact:data:specification:UnqualifiedDataTypesSchemaModule:2">
<cbc:UBLVersionID>2.0</cbc:UBLVersionID>
<cbc:CustomizationID>OIOUBL-2.02</cbc:CustomizationID>
<cbc:ProfileID schemeID="urn:oioubl:id:profileid-1.2" schemeAgencyID="320">urn:www.nesubl.eu:profiles:profile5:ver2.0</cbc:ProfileID>

...

<cac:Item>
    <cbc:Description>Jakke, Allen</cbc:Description>
    <cbc:Name>Clique Jakke, Allen</cbc:Name>
    <cac:SellersItemIdentification>
        <cbc:ID schemeID="n/a">020957-99_L</cbc:ID>
    </cac:SellersItemIdentification>
    <cac:BuyersItemIdentification>
        <cbc:ID schemeID="n/a">JAKKEL</cbc:ID>
    </cac:BuyersItemIdentification>
</cac:Item>
```

But when I validate on http://www.oioubl.net/validator/ I get the message

The structure of the XmlDocument is NOT valid.

Source:System.Xml

Message:The element 'Item' in namespace 'urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonAggregateComponents-2' has invalid child element 'BuyersItemIdentification' in namespace 'urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonAggregateComponents-2'. 
List of possible elements expected: 'ManufacturersItemIdentification, StandardItemIdentification, CatalogueItemIdentification, AdditionalItemIdentification, CatalogueDocumentReference, 
ItemSpecificationDocumentReference, OriginCountry, CommodityClassification, TransactionConditions, HazardousItem, ClassifiedTaxCategory, AdditionalItemProperty, ManufacturerParty, InformationContentProviderParty, OriginAddress, ItemInstance' in 
namespace 'urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonAggregateComponents-2'.

As far as I can read BuyersItemIdentification is a valid child of Item.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the [schema](https://docs.oasis-open.org/ubl/cs-UBL-2.0/xsd/common/UBL-CommonAggregateComponents-2.0.xsd), `cac:BuyersItemIdentification` should come before `cac:SellersItemIdentification`, which is why it is invalid. I would expect that if they are swapped, it will validate successfully.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Invoice xsi:schemaLocation="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:Invoice-2 UBL-Invoice-2.0.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:Invoice-2" xmlns:cac="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonAggregateComponents-2" xmlns:cbc="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonBasicComponents-2" xmlns:ccts="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CoreComponentParameters-2" xmlns:sdt="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:SpecializedDatatypes-2" xmlns:udt="urn:un:unece:uncefact:data:specification:UnqualifiedDataTypesSchemaModule:2">
<cbc:UBLVersionID>2.0</cbc:UBLVersionID>
<cbc:CustomizationID>OIOUBL-2.02</cbc:CustomizationID>
<cbc:ProfileID schemeID="urn:oioubl:id:profileid-1.2" schemeAgencyID="320">urn:www.nesubl.eu:profiles:profile5:ver2.0</cbc:ProfileID>

...

<cac:Item>
    <cbc:Description>Jakke, Allen</cbc:Description>
    <cbc:Name>Clique Jakke, Allen</cbc:Name>
   <cac:BuyersItemIdentification>
        <cbc:ID schemeID="n/a">JAKKEL</cbc:ID>
    </cac:BuyersItemIdentification>
    <cac:SellersItemIdentification>
        <cbc:ID schemeID="n/a">020957-99_L</cbc:ID>
    </cac:SellersItemIdentification>
</cac:Item>
```

Comment: Thanks, I dodn't know the order of elements were important, as long as the proper parent/child relation was kept. I got wiser today.